# JQuery Autocomplete did not go well in symfony2

Tags: symfony, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm having a problem when using auto complete in symfony2.
At this I use the autocomplete jquery UI library, and I had to include it on my twig page.

But when I try to run this autocomplete, nothing appears when I type something in my text input.

I have tried to look for a solution in Google, but still not successful.
This my php coding in symfony2:

```
$students = $this->getDoctrine()
->getRepository('DSBBundle:Student')
->findAll();

$key=1;
$student_name = array();
foreach ($students as $student)
{
  $student_name[$key] = '"'.$student->getName().'",';
  $key++;
}
```

This is syntax in form builder :

```
->add('student', 'text', array(
                    'label' => 'NID Siswa',
                    'attr'   =>  array('class'=>'student')
```

And this is the javascript syntax in my twig:

```
<script>
  var nama = [
  {% for key, student in students %}
      {{ student }}
  {% endfor %}
  ];


  $( ".student" ).autocomplete({
    source: nama
  });
</script>
```

Please help me, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you rigth:

1) You should better do first iteration as it like:

```
$student_name = array();
foreach ($students as $key => $student)
{
  $student_name[$key] = '"'.$student->getName().'",';
}
```

Looks better right?

2) Have you loged your `nama` array? What is this?

```
  var nama = [
  {% for key, student in students %}
      {{ student }}
  {% endfor %}
  ];
```

Take a look to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928729/use-javascript-to-access-a-variable-passed-through-twig), it might help you to convert your array withou any extra things.

Hope this will help to you somehow :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Data transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html)

And in your case look at [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334289/adding-jquery-autocomplete-in-symfony2-entity-field) it helped me