# Symfony 3: How can I implement an EntityType in Form with a lot of objects?

Tags: php, symfony, formbuilder

I have an entity `City` with more than 30000 objects stored. User is able to add an `Address` object with a relation `ManyToOne` to `City`.
But during Form building, the rendering of `<input>` type radio or `select` is not appropriate for the number of objects...

I use the following implementation code (it is a snippet):

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
  /* Pattern to get cities */
  $pattern = 'Bor%';  //I use this filter to reduce the number of objects but not sufficient

  $builder
    ->add('city', EntityType::class, array(
      'class'        => 'AppPlatformBundle:City',
      'choice_label' => 'name',
      'multiple'     => false,
      'expanded'     => true,
      'query_builder'=> function(CityRepository $repository) use($pattern) {
        return $repository->getCitiesWithPattern($pattern);
      }));
}
```

I think that a solution is to use a TextType where the proposals can be selected by the user when he start type anything. But I haven't idea on how implement this.

Do you have a solution on my issue please?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding JQuery Autocomplete in Symfony2 Entity field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334289/adding-jquery-autocomplete-in-symfony2-entity-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this steps :

1. Create a custom form type inheriting from a simple TextType
2. Use this custom form type with a javascript autocomplete plugin and an ajax call
3. Create your custom action in order to retrieve your choices for your select box (created by the plugin)
4. Use a Data Transformer in your custom form type in order to retrieve objects instead of values

Comment: Thank you Fabien, I try your solution and come back when I get result :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much Fabien.

I was able to implement a good solution for me :)

So for anyone interrested by my solution:

I define city field as HiddenField like:

```
  $builder
    ->add('city', HiddenType::class);
```

I use a [Data Transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html) to convert `City` object into unique Id (field Id of the object)

In Twig template, I implement [jQuery-ui Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote)

In backend, I create a route able to return a Json response with all cities filtered by the `term` of jQuery plugin.

In frontend, I develop a jquery script that append a new field "city" with type `Text` and autocomplete action.

When response is received, I fill the field `city` with type `Hidden` with the id.